# Heavy traffic causes ethernet link to go down

Tags: freebsd, 10gbethernet

I have a FreeBSD (10) host connected to a Linux (Debian 7) box directly with a Cat 6 cable.

Both hosts have Intel X-540 10GBe NICs (ixbge).

Whenever there is heavy traffic (high PPS) from the FreeBSD side, the Link state between the adapters go down. Setting FC (Autoneg, RX/TX, all) off seems to not have any effect on this.

Neither OS kernels log anything useful, only message is about `<interface>: NIC Link is Down`
After a half a second or so, the links goes back up.

1. What might be the cause? or,
2. how to troubleshoot this?

**EDIT**:

Tested with packet generator: It seems that it is **exactly** 8188 packets that get through and 8189th causes the link go down, *regardless of packet size*

**EDIT 2**:
This seems to be the transmitting end (FreeBSD) that is to blame, connecting the port in question to another port on the same host yields the exact same results.

Comment: Is the number of packets to trigger the problem the same regardless of packet rate? Or can you send more packets before the problem happens, if you send them at a lower rate?

Comment: Requires a hot packet rate, and 8188 seems oddly close to 8192... Might be that there are 4 unrelated packets every time...

Comment: I had also such hard times with beelding-edge things on freebsd. A little kernel recompilation handled this problem.

Comment: Whenever this happens, grab following o/p on FreeBSD box and paste or link them: 0) uname -a 1) netstat -m 2) vmstat -z 3) sysctl -a (this one would be huge, pastebin it)

Comment: It'd also be useful to see 1,2 and 3 before the problem and after the problem.